Why won't this terminal in visual studio code continue past returning a single integer?
As a personal project of mine, I'm working on making a (semi functional) video game completely made in python. Only problem is I seem to be constantly running into issues working with terminals inside VS code. The current problem is the fact that the terminal seems to just freeze after returning a test value of one.
import time
import random

buildVer = 0.1
playerHealth = 5
enemyHealth = 1
encounterAcitve = 0
welcomeComplete = 0


def anyKey():
    input("Press any key to continue...")

def welcome():
    print("~Project by Broclly~")
    print("")
    print("")
    time.sleep(1/4)
    print("Greetings, welcome to Rogue.py!")
    time.sleep(1/4)
    print("This project is to test the limits of using Python as a game engine!")
    time.sleep(1/4)
    print("Current Build Version:", buildVer)
    anyKey()

def enemyTurn():
    enemyHit = random.randint(0,2)
    playerHealth = playerHealth - enemyHit
    print("You were hit for", enemyHit, "damage!")

def playerTurn():
    playerHit = random.randint(0,1)
    enemyHealth = enemyHealth - playerHit
    print("You hit the enemy for", playerHit, "damage!")

def check():
    if playerHealth <= 0:
        print("You died! Try again :(")
        time.sleep(1)

def enemyEncounter():
    while encounterAcitve == 1:
        enemyTurn()
        playerTurn()
    

while playerHealth > 0:
    while welcomeComplete == 0:
        welcome()
        welcomeComplete = 1
        print(welcomeComplete)
    enemyEncounter()

I expect this to run a bunch of calculations, as well as printing multiple messages, but it seems to only return a test value of 1 I added to make sure the "welcomeComplete" var was working.

The programm "sticks" in the last line:
while playerHealth > 0: ... enemyEncounter(), because the function enemyEncounter returns immediately:
Everything before while encounterAcitve == 1: will work, but after it, it won't, because the condition is not given (see l. 7: encounterAcitve = 0).
When you add something like print("hello") after def enemyEncounter:, it will give you many hellos in the terminal.
PS: Did you call it encounterAcitve intentionally, or should it be encounterActive?

I accidentally set it to encounterAcitve instead of encounterActive, should've just slept instead of late night programming!  Thanks for the help!
